# Not able to access shared folders while running my application as a windows service

Tags: java, windows, windows-services

I've some shared folders on one machine and my app(built with Java) on another machine writes some files to them. For some reason, when running the app as service I'm getting file related exceptions, but the same is working fine when the app is invoked from command line as an administrator. I even tried changing the logon role of my service to "Administrator" but that didn't help. All the shared folders' permissions seem correct as well. Any clues on what is going wrong?

Comment: When you access shared folders, you do so as yourself.  By default, services don't run as you, they run as local system (or perhaps local service or network service) so they can't access shared folders.  Unless you're in a domain, you would need to change the "Log on as" option for the service to your username and provide your password.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes, I did change the "Log on" role and gave my password, but that didn't work.

Comment: Do the exceptions include a Win32 error code?  If not, Process Monitor (available from the MS web site) might help identify the error code.  Are the username and password the same on both machines?  Is the share explicitly configured to allow the user to access it, or only to allow administrators to access it?

Comment: No, logs didn't contain any Win32 error code. Share is actually very liberal; accessible for everyone. I'll try to use PM to see if it can point out any problems. Thanks.

Comment: Also look for logon errors in the Security event log on the remote machine.  (You might need to change local security policy to get it to log these.)